# FormFlow vs Dialogs in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, dialog, botframework, formflow

Can anyone explain me when is better to use Dialogs than FormFlow? 
In my case I do not have to provide a lot of options for user to choose (like in Sandwich bot example), but I'm going to have a lot of logic. For example: if user says something, I'm analyzing his answer by LUIS model and then call a particular method. Depending on what the user said I need to call different methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dialogs are more flexible. While FormFlow allows to navigate between fields back and forward, you cannot do more, for example, change order of the fields depending on user input. At the same time, Dialogs allow you to build complex things, like switching from one scenario to another at any moment, or execution of only part of the scenario.

Real example of a bot I've implemented with Dialogs (and I have no idea how to do it with FormFlow):

1. React on some user intent and ask for a location.
2. Given a location make a search. If something is found, then ask for a contact information.
3. Given a contact information provide a third-party service (which requires a contact information).

Depending on user's input this scenario can work from the beginning to the end, from any stage to the end, or it could be interrupted on any stage (if user rejects to provide location or contact information).